# phpmyadmin : Depends: php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser (< 5~~) but 5.4.0-1 is to be installed

Tags: apt, dependencies, phpmyadmin

After dist-upgrade of my debian, from 10.5 to 10.6 I have this small problem

I cannot upgrade this package

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser
```

I thought to install but debian ask me to remove phpmyadmin. and not is a good idea I think

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  phpmyadmin
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser
```

Then I thought to install both phpmyadmin and php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser but I've another stall

```
apt install phpmyadmin php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
phpmyadmin is already the newest version (4:4.9.5+dfsg1-2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser (< 5~~) but 5.4.0-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried

```
 dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

But it gives me no results. Zero output

So I tried using aptitude, but aptitude asked me to remove phpmyadmin

```
# aptitude install php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 78.4 kB of archives. After unpacking 12.3 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser (< 5~~) but 5.4.0-1 is to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:
1)     phpmyadmin [4:4.9.5+dfsg1-2 (now, unstable)]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

So I removed but phpmyadmin and php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser then I tried to reinstall only phpmyadmin

```
# apt install phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser (< 5~~) but 5.4.0-1 is to be installed
              Recommends: php-bz2
              Recommends: php-tcpdf but it is not going to be installed
```

So I ended up to not being able on install phpmyadmin at all

My sources.list

```
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian buster main
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian buster main

deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian-security buster/updates main

deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian buster-updates main
```

And this is the content of alll additional .list files in sources.list.d

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib

deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ buster main

deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main
```

What can I do to unlock this situation?

### Suggested solutions and esits

I cannot remove

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib
```

because removing this will make phpmyadmin unavailable, no candidate to install

--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re running into issues because you have the unstable repository configured, and `phpmyadmin` isn’t installable there currently. `phpmyadmin` isn’t available in Debian 10, but it is available and installable from backports, without risking upgrading (parts of) your system to unstable.

To fix your setup:

1. remove unstable from your list of repositories
2. add backports:

   ```
   echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. install the backported `phpmyadmin`:

   ```
   sudo apt install -t buster-backports phpmyadmin
   ```

You’ll probably run into problems caused by packages you’ve ended up installing from unstable; you’ll need to downgrade those manually, by running the same `apt install` command as above, replacing `phpmyadmin` with the packages you need to downgrade (or adding them to the `phpmyadmin` `apt install` command).

Comment: If I remove unstable repositories, there is no candidate for phpmyadmin, so the 2nd option is not available

Comment: Option 3 not available:  same unmet dependecies error, plus another, new, dependency error with php-twig

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten that it’s not available in Debian 10. You need to use backports instead of unstable.

Comment: Damn I added backports but .... ```phpmyadmin : Depends: php-twig (>= 2.9) but 2.6.2-2 is to be installed```

Comment: What command are you using to install `phpmyadmin`? The correct version of `php-twig` is available in backports.

Comment: After adding backports to a new, empty source.list.d/phpmyadmin.list, I run `apt update` and `apt install phpmyadmin`. Anyway, I resolved removing phpmyadmin and installing manually. No more backports, no more unstable.. I am sorry bvut I see only now the missing ` -t buster-backports`