# Why my debian server release is bullseye/sid?

Tags: debian

At today, 13 of october of 2020, the stable release of debian is 'buster'.

I tried to ask my serve which is the current release and it's surprising

```
cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid \n \l
```

Why did this happens? Can I safely return to buster stable and how ? How to avoid to go to an unstable release?  Could it be happened doing a `apt dist-upgrade`?

Comment: How is it surprising?  What did you actually install and configure in the first place?

Comment: It is surprising because I'm not a linux expert and because I'm, not the only who touched the server. I installed only nginx, mariadb server and phpmyadmin. I'm documenting now on what a release is for debian and when / what happens in a dist-upgrade, if is it involved at all.. I'm lacking info but I'm actively documenting.

Comment: But as the answer is telling you upgraded your system to unstable, yourself, by using this line: `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib`

Comment: @A.B: Yes, it's true, but I discovered / understood this only yesterday, after studying answer and more documents found on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the setup described in [phpmyadmin : Depends: php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser (< 5~~) but 5.4.0-1 is to be installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/614269/86440), this happened because you’ve upgraded to Debian unstable. Adding unstable to your repositories, without specifying a default release in `apt`’s configuration, would result in a partial upgrade to unstable the next time your ran `apt upgrade`, or a full upgrade if you ran `apt full-upgrade` (or `dist-upgrade`).

Reverting isn’t supported, but you can try; see [How to revert Debian from testing to stable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451968/86440) for details, replacing `stretch` with `buster` and `/testing` with `/unstable`.

To avoid such issues in the future, [don’t mix stable releases with in-development releases](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian?highlight=%28FrankenDebian%29#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian). The only suite you should add to a Debian stable setup, unless you really know what you’re doing, is [Debian Backports](https://backports.debian.org/) (if you need backported packages).

Comment: The debian unstable repo has been added to lazyt-installing phpmyadmin. I removed phpmyadmin, the related apt source list entry and then installed phpmyadmin using downloaded zip... less easy to mantain but I think I avoid more problem in the future. Sad, a lot of phpmyadmin tutorial suggest to add unstable package to debian.  Next time I will comment tutorial with my bad experience

Comment: The simplest solution is to install `phpmyadmin` from backports, as explained in the other question.